# How to temporarely resolve a name to a localhost port?

Tags: linux, dns, localhost, resolve

I develop websites with rails, and I was looking for a simple way to setup a dynamic name resolution for my app. The final product I need is to is: Every time I start a rails application (by typing rails server on my application folder, I want to run it on a random port and if I type the application name on my browser (like myapp.dev or something) it resolves to the localhost on the correct port.

The part of getting the app name and generating a random port is not the problem. The problem is how to resolve a name to a local port. Is there any simple tool on linux that allows me to do this?

Right now, the best I can think off is start a daemon that keeps track of when a rails app is started, annotate the port, and add an entry to itself in `/etc/host` with the app name. Then, whenever it receives a request, it forward to the correct app based on the name.

I can't believe this is the best way so ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but DNS it not about ports. By using DNS you can resolve the name to IP not port or from IP to name (RevDNS). What you would do in your case is during start up of application on random port,  forward another port which will be always the same.

For instance:

By iptables forward port 80 to random port of your application. Then you will always get to application by port 80.

Edit: I couldn't paste it in the comment because it's too long, so I give you answer here:

You can create a lot of iptables rules and first application will be on port 80, next 81, and so on.In browser you have to type then: apps.test.com (first app) , apps.test.com:81 (second app)..
Another solution: if you want to have diffrent domains (not type a port after colon), you can use proxy server,
and use VirtualHost to redirect to particular apps. In proxy configuration you can define that app1.test.com goes to port e.g 8888, app2.test.com goes to port 8889 and then during start up your app you can create iptables rule or ssh tunel to redirect whole traffic from port 8888 to your random port of 
ruby application. To don't do it more complicated, it would be nice that these port
which you configure in proxy, are not used by your ruby application. Also you can check, iptables
"string match" option; Match Host field of HTTP request and then analogously during start up apps,
create iptables rule which will redirect everything which goes to port 80 with specify Host field to 
your ruby app port. The last option would be using SRV dns record, but it's rather useless in your
situation. But anyway you can play around with all of these options, and choose one which is the best for
you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this way I can only have one application running at same time, since all applications use port 80, right? Now that you said that DNS is not about ports, I think there will be no other way unless using a deamon as I proposed, since the browser will have to do all requests to port 80. Right?